# How do you shorten a component name in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Hey guys is there any way that I can shorten the name I used for the menuhelper like I did with the react component on the first line.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { MenuHelper } from "@core/shared/menu/MenuHelper";
```

I've tried this:

```
import * as CH from "@core/shared/menu/MenuHelper";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To alias a named import, you need to put the `as` inside the curly braces:

```
import { MenuHelper as CH } from "@core/shared/menu/MenuHelper";
```

To see the full list of valid import types and what they all mean, see [the relevant MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) (TypeScript largely follows the same semantics as JavaScript, so it's equally valid for both).